# Why doesn't my custom component update when I change properties?

Tags: delphi, components, vcl, custom-component

I have created a component, TGridPaintBox, based on TPaintBox. It is basically a paintbox with added "grid functionality". It's not a data grid. More like a chess board component.

In the object explorer I can set certain properties. Most importantly I can set the grid dimensions (how many cells across/down), but also options relating to drawing. Whether the cells should be square, the color of odd/even cells etc.

My first version of this component had properties directly on the class, and when I changed a property, the designtime drawing was updated immediately. As the component grew, I wanted to organize my properties a little better, and introduced some "options properties", like drawing options, behaviour options etc. After introducing this, the designtime drawing no longer updates like before. After changing a property, I have to click on the component for it to update. Can anyone tell me why this happens?

Here's a stripped down version of the code. I hope it will explain the behaviour:

(PS: This is my first component, even though I've been using Delphi since 1997, so if anyone can spot anything stupid in the way I've done it, please feel free to tell me)

```
unit GridPaintBox;

interface

type
  TGridDrawOption = (gdoSquareCells,gdoCenterCells,gdoDrawCellEdges,gdoDrawFocus);
  TGridDrawOptions = set of TGridDrawOption;

  TGridOptions = class(TPersistent)
  private
    FCellsX : integer;
    FCellsY : integer;
    FDrawOptions : TGridDrawOptions;
  public
    constructor Create(aGridPaintBox : TGridPaintBox);
    procedure Assign(Source : TPersistent); override;
  published
    property CellsX : integer read FCellsX write FCellsX;
    property CellsY : integer read FCellsY write FCellsY;
    property DrawOptions : TGridDrawOptions read FDrawOptions write FDrawOptions;
  end;

  TGridPaintBox = class(TPaintBox)
  private
    FGridOptions : TGridOptions;
    FFocusedX,
    FFocusedY : integer;
    FOnFocusChanged: TNotifyEvent; 
    procedure CalculateSizeAndPosition; 
    procedure DrawCell(X,Y : integer);
    procedure DrawCells;
    procedure SetGridOptions(const Value: TGridOptions);
  protected
    procedure MouseDown(Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer); override;
  public
    constructor Create(aOwner : TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure Paint; override;
    procedure SetFocus(X,Y : integer);
  published
    property OnFocusChanged : TNotifyEvent read FOnFocusChanged write FOnFocusChanged;
    property Options : TGridOptions read FGridOptions write SetGridOptions;
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('Samples', [TGridPaintBox]);
end;

procedure TGridPaintBox.CalculateSizeAndPosition;
begin
  <...>
end;

constructor TGridPaintBox.Create(aOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  FGridOptions := TGridOptions.Create(self);
end;

procedure TGridPaintBox.DrawCell(X, Y: integer);
begin
  <...>
end;

procedure TGridPaintBox.DrawCells;
var
  X,Y : integer;
begin
  CalculateSizeAndPosition;

  for Y := 0 to FGridOptions.CellsY-1 do
    for X := 0 to FGridOptions.CellsX-1 do
      DrawCell(X,Y);
end;

procedure TGridPaintBox.Paint;
begin
  Canvas.Font := Font;
  Canvas.Brush.Color := Color;
  Canvas.Brush.Style := bsSolid;
  Canvas.FillRect(Rect(0,0,Width,Height));
  DrawCells;
  if Assigned(OnPaint) then
    OnPaint(Self); 
end;

procedure TGridPaintBox.SetGridOptions(const Value: TGridOptions);
begin
  FGridOptions.Assign(Value);
  invalidate;
end;

procedure TGridPaintBox.MouseDown(Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  SetFocus(PixelToCellX(X),PixelToCellY(Y));
  inherited;
end;

procedure TGridPaintBox.SetFocus(X, Y: integer);
begin
  if (FocusedX=X) and (FocusedY=Y) then 
    exit;

  FFocusedX := X;
  FFocusedY := Y;

  if assigned(OnFocusChanged) then
    OnFocusChanged(self);

  invalidate;
end;

constructor TGridOptions.Create(aGridPaintBox : TGridPaintBox);
begin
  FCellsX := 20;
  FCellsY := 8;
  FDrawOptions := [gdoSquareCells,gdoCenterCells,gdoDrawCellEdges];
end;

procedure TGridOptions.Assign(Source : TPersistent);
begin
  if Source is TGridOptions then
  begin
    FCellsX := TGridOptions(Source).CellsX;
    FCellsY := TGridOptions(Source).CellsY;
    FDrawOptions := TGridOptions(Source).DrawOptions;
  end
  else
    inherited;
end;

end.
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It happens because you don't have a setter for the options set which would invalidate your control which belongs to. The click in the form designer invokes the control to invalidate though, but you should handle this by your own in such options setter. So I would store the options owner for better access to the direct owner class instance and in the options setter force this owner, the control to redraw:

```
type
  TGridPaintBox = class;
  TGridDrawOption = (gdoSquareCells, gdoCenterCells, gdoDrawCellEdges, gdoDrawFocus);
  TGridDrawOptions = set of TGridDrawOption;
  TGridOptions = class(TPersistent)
  private
    FOwner: TGridPaintBox;
    FCellsX: Integer;
    FCellsY: Integer;
    FDrawOptions: TGridDrawOptions;
    procedure SetCellsX(AValue: Integer);
    procedure SetCellsY(AValue: Integer);
    procedure SetDrawOptions(const AValue: TGridDrawOptions);
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TGridPaintBox);
    procedure Assign(ASource: TPersistent); override;
  published
    property CellsX: Integer read FCellsX write SetCellsX;
    property CellsY: Integer read FCellsY write SetCellsY;
    property DrawOptions: TGridDrawOptions read FDrawOptions write SetDrawOptions;
  end;

implementation

constructor TGridOptions.Create(AOwner: TGridPaintBox);
begin
  FOwner := AOwner;
  FCellsX := 20;
  FCellsY := 8;
  FDrawOptions := [gdoSquareCells, gdoCenterCells, gdoDrawCellEdges];
end;

procedure TGridOptions.SetCellsX(AValue: Integer);
begin
  if FCellsX <> AValue then
  begin
    FCellsX := AValue;
    FOwner.Invalidate;
  end;
end;

procedure TGridOptions.SetCellsY(AValue: Integer);
begin
  if FCellsY <> AValue then
  begin
    FCellsY := AValue;
    FOwner.Invalidate;
  end;
end;

procedure TGridOptions.SetDrawOptions(const AValue: TGridDrawOptions);
begin
  if FDrawOptions <> AValue then
  begin
    FDrawOptions := AValue;
    FOwner.Invalidate;
  end;
end;
```

***Further notes:***

If you don't explicitly need to have paint box' published properties and events like for instance `Color`, `Font` or `OnPaint` event, derive your control from `TGraphicControl` instead of from `TPaintBox`. You can choose what properties and events will you publish by your own.

Comment: Yeah, typo. It's actually in the TGridPaintBox class, but I messed up when editing for this post. I'll update my question.

Comment: Also, thanks for the tip about deriving from TGraphicControl rather than TPaintBox. And of course, thanks for the rest of the answer. It solved my problem :-)